# Query returns 0, but my conditional statement isn't recognizing it as a 0

Tags: bash, sqlite, shell

My Bash script uses SQLite to store data. I'm comparing id's (column `jid`) from table `tester` for which id's are in table `test2`:

```
sqlite3 jail.db "SELECT jid FROM tester" | while read jid; do
   if sqlite3 jail.db "select exists(select 1 from test2 where jid=$jid limit 1)"; then
   echo "i found it"
   else
   echo "i did not find it"
   fi
done
```

Going through id's query returns 0 or 1, but my Bash script executes the 1 part of If/then/else regardless:

```
0
i found it
0
i found it
0
i found it
0
i found it
1
i found it
1
i found it
1
i found it
```

Comment: Just guessing, but I think that, either if your query returns 0 or returns 1, the fact is that the query has been correctly executed, so the error returned by `sqlite3` is zero (which means, everything OK) and your bash conditional is handling it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for a **left outer join**, something like this

```
for r in $(sqlite3 jail.db 'select case when test2.jid != "" then 1 else 0 end from tester left outer join test2 on tester.jid = test2.jid;'); do
    if [[ "$r" == 1 ]]; then
        echo "i found it"
    else
        echo "i did not find it"
    fi
done
```

notice the use of `$()` to get the output of the command not its exit value.

Comment: This works exactly how I was looking for, very much appreciated!